# Selecting groups of rows where at least one row of each group meets a criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm trying to SELECT groups of rows having one row with a certain criteria.

I've tried it with CASE WHEN statements without any success. Keep in mind this table has hundred of records.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

- One row of the group must have a `subcategory` equal to "GAMECONSOLE".
- Rows having the same `category`, `description` and `section` form one group.

The ID is different so MIN and MAX does not work either.

```
ID      SECTION     DESCRIPTION   CATEGORY     SUBCATEGORY
21349   14010014    TODDLER       TOY          GAMECONSOLE
21278   14010014    TODDLER       TOY          BICYCLE 
21431   15020021    TODDLER       TOY          CHESS
```

In this example the two first rows should be selected because they form one group and one row of the group is a "GAMECONSOLE".

Comment: Please provide more information in your sample data and also include a desire output. As you have it now you can have too many answer. Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
  And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @RubahMalam Dont be lazy, at least point to the [**where**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) section in w3schools.

Comment: Sorry for not being too specific  - I want to SELECT all the records that have a unique section. The 'description' and 'category' are the same for all records, some sections have multiple 'id's' (1 to many) as well as multiple 'subcategories' (1 section to many subcategories).  So how can I filter so that the query generates only unique section's but with the condition that a certain subcategory is selected under that section number?  Sorry if I confused anyone.

Comment: @user5202594 You know the charlie brown teacher? Sorry to say, but that is how your explanation sound. If you put a little more effort you could put a better sample data so we understand better instead of waste our time try to guess what you mean.

Comment: I think the question is still confusing.  And I'm not 100% sure that the edited post reflects your thoughts or someone else's interpretation at this point.

Comment: @user5202594: Do my edits reflect your problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

CASE WHEN is used when you have to take a decision within a column expression. Filtering on row level must be done in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT T.id, T.section, T.description, T.category, T.subcategory
FROM
    myTable T
    INNER JOIN myTable S
        ON T.section = S.section AND 
           T.description = S.description AND
           T.category = S.category
WHERE
    S.subcategory = 'GAMECONSOLE'
```

You can join the table with itself on the columns that have to be equal. The table with alias `S` selects the right subategory. `T` selects all corresponding rows of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a1.ID 
     , a1.SECTION 
     , a1.DESCRIPTION
     , a1.CATEGORY
     , a1.SUBCATEGORY 
  FROM  MyTable a1 
 INNER JOIN MyTable a2 ON a2.DESCRIPTION = a1.DESCRIPTION
                      AND a2.CATEGORY = a1.CATEGORY 
                 AND a2.SECTION = a1.SECTION 
   WHERE a2.SUBCATEGORY = 'GAMECONSOLE'
```

-- you may want to further filter the Where clause and apply a group by or distinct to get the actual results you are wanting

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like:

```
select
   ...
from
 (
   select 
     ...
     ,sum(case when subcategory = 'GAMECONSOLE' then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by category, description, section) as cnt
   from tab
 ) dt
where cnt > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM myTable T
 WHERE Section = (SELECT Section
                  FROM myTable Q
                  WHERE Q.subcategory = 'GAMECONSOLE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) you can get the answer without using a self join.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb718/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( ID, SECTION, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY ) AS
          SELECT 1, 1, 'TODDLER', 'TOY', 'GAMECONSOLE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'TODDLER', 'TOY', 'BICYCLE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'TODDLER', 'TOY', 'CHESS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 3, 'COMPUTERS', 'SOFTWARE', 'BOOK' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 4, 'COMPUTERS', 'SOFTWARE', 'SOFTWARE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 5, 'COMPUTERS', 'HARDWARE', 'MONITOR' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 6, 'COMPUTERS', 'HARDWARE', 'GAMECONSOLE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 7, 'COMPUTERS', 'HARDWARE', 'KEYBOARD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 8, 'TODDLER', 'BEDDING', 'BED' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID, SECTION, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE SUBCATEGORY WHEN 'GAMECONSOLE' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY ) AS HAS_SUBCATEGORY
  FROM   TEST t
)
WHERE  HAS_SUBCATEGORY > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb718/5/0)**:

```
| ID | SECTION | DESCRIPTION | CATEGORY | SUBCATEGORY |
|----|---------|-------------|----------|-------------|
|  8 |       7 |   COMPUTERS | HARDWARE |    KEYBOARD |
|  7 |       6 |   COMPUTERS | HARDWARE | GAMECONSOLE |
|  6 |       5 |   COMPUTERS | HARDWARE |     MONITOR |
|  3 |       2 |     TODDLER |      TOY |       CHESS |
|  2 |       1 |     TODDLER |      TOY |     BICYCLE |
|  1 |       1 |     TODDLER |      TOY | GAMECONSOLE |
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE SUBCATEGORY like "GAMECONSOLE";
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE SUBCATEGORY = "GAMECONSOLE";
```

Replace <TABLE_NAME> with the actual table name.

Further readings:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html